# Using register for memory addressing in assembly using fasm assembler?

Tags: assembly, fasm

Ok, so here is my query. Say, when i write the following instruction

`mov ax,[myvar]` ; this basically means to move the value stored at memory address of `myvar` and moving the value in `ax` register.

Now, i found this article which had the following instruction:-

```
mov ax,2
mov bx,4
```

`add ax,[bx]` :- what does [bx] mean?

`add ax, bx` :- this would mean i am simply adding 2 + 4 and storing it in ax

but when i write `add ax,[bx]` what exactly am i adding? I see some sort of weird
address being loaded in the `ax` register.

Can someone please help me understand the code.Thanks

Comment: `add` will add the value in `bx` to the value in `ax` storing the resulting sum in `ax`. You have almost got your thinking right. A register can either hold a `value` (e.g `1,2,3...`) or it can hold a `memory address` where the value is stored (i.e. a pointer `0x950010`). When `bx` contains the memory address holding the value use `[bx]` to specify you wish to add the value at that address to `ax`. If `bx` contains the value (i.e. a literal `2`), then no `[ ]` are needed. In your example what is `myvar`? It is a `label` to a **memory address**, so `[ ]` are required.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin:- Thank you for that explanation. Just to be clear, if i am copying a value such as mov bx,2 then basically i am going to use add ax,bx. But say i am passing the memory address of a variable to bx i.e mov bx, myvar where myvar holds the memory address of size word and value 2. In that case, i shall write add ax,[bx]. Am i correct? Because then i am deferencing the memory address.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but you would be better served moving `[myvar]` into `bx` to begin with.  One of the best resources is [**The Art of Assembly**](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/artofasm/artofasm.html). Look at chapter 4.6 in particular. It covers it all. It is basically for `8086`, but it is 100% applicable to `x86` the register sizes are the only difference.